# Why does my After Effects expression remove my text formatting?

Tags: animation, expression, adobe, after-effects

I'm just trying to create a simple type-on effect for using as a sort of 'lower-third' to show people's names and job titles in videos. I've used a couple of tutorials and put together an expression which does the job, but it removes the formatting from the second line of text.

I want to use the same text layer for both lines (name and job title) so that the blinking cursor carries through to the second line, but I want the second line to be smaller and in a different font. I've styled the type to look as I want it to, but when I apply the expression the second line appears formatted the same as the first.

I've exported to check it's not just a preview thing.

Here's the expression:

```
L = text.sourceText.length;
PT = time - thisLayer.inPoint;
T = PT*effect("Speed")("Slider") - effect("Start at")("Slider")*effect("Speed")("Slider");
Bl = effect("Cursor Blink")("Slider");
F = Math.round((PT*Bl) % 1);

if(F == 1 | (T<L & T>0)){Fl = "|";}else{Fl = ""}

substr(0,T) + Fl
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not due to your expression.
Any expression has this "effect", even just "value;"

You should use text animators (opacity=0 for characters T+2 to 'infinity', and character value for character T+1 (the cursor): use 0 50% of the time and "|".charCodeAt(0) otherwise).

By the way | and & are bitwise operator, you probably mean || and && (logical OR and AND).